# jQuery or javascript syntax that I don't understand

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m reading a Polymer tutorial but I don't understand some code lines, like this:

```
 postTask: function(e) {  // Add a new task
    var tsk = this.$.tTask.value;
    var usr = this.$.tUser.value;
    ...
```

In this code block I don't understand the selector **this.$.tTask.value**, is another way to select in jQuery syntax?

Comment: Note that `$` is a valid JavaScript identifier name. It is the same used by jQuery by coincidence (mostly because it is easily distinguished). It is nothing more that `this.EasyToRememberVarName.tTask.value`. You should look into Polymer documentation for more accurate description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know nothing about Polymer, so I can only answer this question based on javascript syntax.

This code doesn't necessarily involve jQuery.

In javascript, the $ symbol is just an identifier.

When you include jQuery, it happens to assign the `jQuery` function to `window.$`. But jQuery does not 'own' the $ symbol.

Here, a variable with the identifier of `$` has been assigned to the current object. For example, some code somewhere could be calling

```
this.$ = {
      tTask: { value: "TaskValue" },
      tUser: { value: "UserValue" }
};
```